# How to open a file in lua

Tags: windows, lua

How to open a file on desktop in lua program? Is there a simple way to do it?

I'm trying to make a addon for a game so when I'm in combat, It opens my mp3 file on my computer. It's running on Windows 10.

Comment: Thanks for replying quickly! I mean opening a file on windows, not to the program

Comment: You mean to `execute` a windows application?

Comment: Yes, for example, have a lua program start/launch a exe for you.

Comment: If the file extension `.ext` is registered, you can use `os.execute("start file.ext")`.  This question is probably a cross-site duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/246825/open-file-from-the-command-line-on-windows

Comment: Its not a duplicate, windows command line and lua programs are different. And thank you for your help, where do I install `.ext` files? Could `.ext` files run other filetypes?

Comment: `.ext` was meant as placeholder. Running `start filename` will open up whatever application is registered with that filename's extension. Try `os.execute("start myfile.mp3")` and your music player should start.

Comment: @Dubstep My bad. Saw that too late.

Comment: Thank you **Bartek Banachewicz** for your help! You have answered my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I run an executable using Lua?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829404/how-do-i-run-an-executable-using-lua)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a file in it's registered application you can use `os.execute('start [file_path]')`, as stated by Henri and Bartek

the registered application is the application that launches when you double click the file icon, it is determined by the file's extension Examples: `.lua`, `mp3`, `.txt`.

You can find/change the application in the properties window of the file on a windows system:

[image: Properties Window]

The `start` param is not system independent, some systems will require `open` rather then `start`. Related information on determining os: [how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-the-system-from-within-a-lua-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295052/how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-the-system-from-within-a-lua-script)