# I've been learning LUA and want to clear console

Tags: lua, console

I've been tiring to clear my console to make it neater, I've tried `os.execute("clear")` (which is similar to what I use in python)
this is the whole program:

```
    while( true )
    do
        local opacity
        print("What do you want the opacity to be? (invisible is 1, solid is 0)")
        opacity = io.read()
        opacity = tonumber(opacity)
        if opacity >1 then
            print("Thats not correct, try again")
            os.execute("clear")
            elseif opacity <=1 then
            print(opacity)
        end
    end
```

SOLUTION HAS BEEN FOUND: require = os needed to be added for the os commands to work

Comment: Try `print("\27c")`

Comment: One Up @Egor - Because it works without os.execute() and without TERM variable. - Now lets get ```\27``` from string.char() without extra line break with io.write(): ```io.write(("%s%s"):format(string.char(27), "c"))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows:

```
os.execute("cls")
```

On Unix:

```
os.execute("clear")
```

Comment: The problem is I have no idea what OS I'm using, I'm on a website called replit and I know its Linux but not exactly what type

Comment: You can use the technique mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295052/how-can-i-determine-the-os-of-the-system-from-within-a-lua-script) to determine the operating system.

Comment: i seem to be on a Unix however os.execute("clear") dosent seem to work, do i need to import os like in python?

Comment: @erro50282069 probably neither one works on replit because it's a web browser

Comment: ive found my problem, i didnt have `require = os` in there, the program now works